# Undefined variable: $message in Email template

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use `$message->embed($pathToFile)` within my Markdown template for sending emails.

However I get the following error message

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>
> Undefined variable: message

In the documentation it says that Laravel automatically passes `$message` variable, and it's available to all email templates.
What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use markup to embed images by using the following format:

```
![ImageAltText](PathToImage)
```

For example, you could pass the path of an image using

`$user->avatarPath = Storage::url($image);`

to your markdown template and utilize it like so

```
![User_Avatar]({{$user->avatarPath}})
```

**NOTE:** If you are on a local development environment (meaning you a using localhost / 127.0.0.1), then images will NOT show in the email client. This is because the email client will not be able to recognize the image domain path, for example:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/avatars/my_avatar.jpg`

This will simple show as a broken image within the email client, you must use a publicly accessible domain!